# Freemarker Dynamically call localized string

Tags: localization, freemarker

Thanks in advance.

I have few status codes coming from database. Example 200, 205, etc.

In my language file, I have strings like -

```
VA_PRODCODE_200=Valid Product
VA_PRODCODE_205=Limited Edition Product
```

From ftl, I am trying translate the strings as below.

```
${"VA_PRODCODE_" + productstatus.productStatusCode}
```

where productstatus.productStatusCode is coming from database and have values like 200, 205

But the result is always coming as:

```
VA_PRODCODE_200
VA_PRODCODE_205
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this translation.

Thanks
Dibs

Comment: Depends... How do you print things from your language file when the key is not dynamic?

Comment: I pass the values to the ftl using key value pair.

Then on the ftl, I print it using ${PRINT_THIS}

This prints the appropriate value from language file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable is in the data-model, like this:

```
${.data['VA_PRODCODE_' + productstatus.productStatusCode?c]}
```

`?c` is there to prevent localized number formatting, which can do things like adding thousand separators. (You could also use `.vars`, which works both for locals and data-model variables.)

Comment: That was of great help. This code worked - `${.vars['VA_PRODCODE_' + productstatus.productStatusCode]}`  
  
I could not use `?c` as this is the value was string and not integer.